# Stop the flood of questions about the broken YouTube API

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow

Google has updated the YouTube Iframe API, which contained [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4706). This has lead to a flood of questions on Stack Overflow.

Please close the following questions as a duplicate of the "work-around" question. Most other questions received an answer along the lines of "This is a known bug, see [link to bug report]".

Question with work-around:

- [YouTube iframe player API - OnStateChange not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078094/youtube-api-onstatechange-not-firing)

Duplicates:

- [Is the YouTube JavaScript (iframe) player broken today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075201/is-the-youtube-javascript-iframe-player-broken-today) (closed as off-topic..? Should be a dupe)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077220/youtube-iframe-player-api-loadvideobyid-stopped-working
- [playVideo and stopVideo no longer work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075972/playvideo-and-stopvideo-no-longer-work)
- [YouTube API changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075253/youtube-api-changes)
- [Why is the YouTube JavaScript API OnPlayerStateChange event handler no longer working? Is this a catastrophic bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091095/why-is-youtube-js-api-onplayerstatechange-event-handler-no-longer-working-is-th)
- [onPlayerStateChange YouTube API doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085080/onplayerstatechange-youtube-api-doesnt-work)
- [YouTube HTML5 API works fine, but displays 'origin' error in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084757/youtube-html5-api-works-fine-but-displays-origin-error-in-console)
- [YouTube iframe_api Google example does not work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075802/youtube-iframe-api-google-example-does-not-work-anymore)
- [YouTube iframe API events not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072906/youtube-iframe-api-events-not-working-in-firefox)

Watch the [youtube-api](/questions/tagged/youtube-api), [youtube](/questions/tagged/youtube), [youtube-javascript-api](/questions/tagged/youtube-javascript-api) tags for more duplicates.

Comment: @Robert Could you also re-open http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075201/is-the-youtube-javascript-iframe-player-broken-today, and close it again as Duplicate? It's currently marked as "Off-topic", which is not true. Furthermore, the canonical question/answer offers valuable information to Googlers.